# Use async pipe in ngFor on Observable of Observables (Angular)

Tags: angular, angular-template, angular-pipe

I have variable defined like this: `myVar: Observable<Observable<MyObject>[]>`.

I am using Angular4 feature to enumerate with async pipe

```
*ngFor="let obsMyObject of (myVar | async)"
```

now I have Observable of MyObject, but I need just MyObject. I could write something like that:

```
<div *ngFor="let obsMyObject of (myVar | async)">
    <div *ngIf="let obsMyObject | async; let MyObject"></div>
</div>
```

but I can not do this in inner div, because I am setting `flex order` (which doesn't have any effect on inner div) property so I need something like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let obsMyObject of (myVar | async); let MyObject = (obsMyObject | async)"
    [style.order]="MyObject.order">
</div>
```

I just had one idea how to do this, and I tried this:

```
<div *ngFor="let obsMyObject of (myVar | async); let MyObject = obsMyObject)">
    {{MyObject}}
</div>
```

but MyObject is undefined, so there is no way `let MyObject = (obsMyObject | async)` would work.

Comment: What should be the difference between `obsMyObject` and `MyObject`?

Comment: Why do you have an observable of an observable? It sounds like you need to rewrite whatever provides it, e.g. to use flatMap rather than map.

Comment: `obsMyObject` is `BehaviorSubject<MyObject>` and as that I can not use it to set style.order property.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use an `ng-container` and an `ngIf` to subscribe and create reference to the observable. Then from within the `ng-container` you can reference this new variable as if it was a plain object.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="myVar$| async as myVar">
   <div *ngFor="let obsMyObject of myVar">
    {{obsMyObject }}
   </div>
</ng-container>
```

The use of myVar and object is really confusing.  Here's a better example:

**Property in component declared as:**

```
users$: Observable<User[]>
```

**And the template:**

```
<ng-container *ngIf="users$ | async as users">
   <div *ngFor="let user of users">
     {{ user.name }}
   </div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: This is not it. I have `Observable<Observable<User>[]>` which is not `Observable<User[]>`. I need 2 Observables, because both array of users and user changes.