# Angular ngfor selected from another array not working

Tags: angular, angularfire5

Sorry the title might be a bit confusing, but this is the problem.

This is the code I use.

```html
<option #groupid
        *ngFor="let group of groups | async"
        [value]="group.id"
        [selected]="(announcement | async)?.group_id == group.id ? true : null">
  {{ group.name }}
</option>
```

`(announcement | async)?.group_id` is showing as null, but when I use it outside the `ngFor`, it shows the correct number.

Is that because of the `ngFor`?

Comment: Try using the `as` keyword as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47729570/use-async-pipe-in-ngfor-on-observable-of-observables-angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you should do it

```js
<div *ngIf="announcement | async; let announce">
  <option #groupid
          *ngFor="let group of groups | async"
          [value]="group.id"
          [selected]="announce.group_id == group.id ? true : false">
    {{ group.name }}
  </option>
</div>
```

Comment: The only issue I have with this code, is that when I want to save the value of the option I selected, I get `Cannot read property 'value' of undefined` error, which is related to the *ngIf, because when I remove the ngIf, the error is gone. Is there a way to use the ngIf and not getting the error?

Comment: Ok, so I know I can do this with concat. The problem is that I have 2 observables (from firebase), one getting items from a child with a specific key and the other getting the all items from another child. When trying to concat those, I only see the items from the specific child/key. Checking the other child (in chrome), it shows a collapsed tree item (empty name), then shows the items. Is this the reason why they won't concat?